# ServletFilter - changing URL does not work

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I have a GWT application which URL is `.../Organizer.html`. I would like to access it also from url `.../organizer`. So I decided to replace the original `HttpServletRequest` with the wrapper with overriden `getRequestURL()` and `getRequestURI()` methods in a servlet filter.

Filter code:

```
String[] urlSplit = req.getRequestURL().toString().split("/");
String urlEnd = urlSplit[urlSplit.length -1];


if (urlEnd.equals(ORGANIZER_URL_ALTERNATIVE)){
    String newUrl = req.getRequestURL().toString().
            replace(ORGANIZER_URL_ALTERNATIVE, ORGANIZER_URL);
    String newUri = req.getRequestURI().toString().
            replace(ORGANIZER_URL_ALTERNATIVE, ORGANIZER_URL);
    request = new ChangeUrlRequest(req, newUrl, newUri);

}

//Just to check if it works
req =  (HttpServletRequest) request;
System.out.println(req.getRequestURL());
System.out.println(req.getRequestURI());

chain.doFilter(request, response);
```

---

Request wrapper:

```
class ChangeUrlRequest extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {


    private StringBuffer newUrlBuffer;
    private String newUri;

    public ChangeUrlRequest(HttpServletRequest request,String newUrl, String newUri) {
        super(request);

        newUrlBuffer = new StringBuffer(newUrl);
        this.newUri = newUri;
    }

    @Override
    public StringBuffer getRequestURL() {
        return newUrlBuffer;
    }

    @Override
    public String getRequestURI() {
        return newUri;
    }

}
```

This works as expected in way that I can use `.../organizer` and is replaced by `.../Organizer.html`

The problem I have now is that even if the URL/URI is the same whether I access .../organizer or .../Organizer.html from browser, only the .../Organizer.html works and for .../organizer the Tomcat complains it cannot find the page:  **HTTP Status 404 - /my-page/Organizer.html**

The output of `System.out` from the code above:

with Organizer.html (works):

URL: `http://localhost:8080/my-page/Organizer.html`
URI: `/my-page/Organizer.html`

with organizer (gives above mentiond 404):

URL: `http://localhost:8080/my-page/Organizer.html`
URI: `/my-page/Organizer.html`

Do I need to override or change also something else?

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is to be able to access the app by either URL, maybe there is a simpler solution. You could write a servlet accessible at `/organizer` and forward the request to the HTML page, e.g.:

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns="/organizer")
public class OrganizerServlet extends HttpServlet {
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/Organizer.html");
        dispatcher.forward(request,response);
    }
}
```

Note that you may need to modify the paths for `/organizer` and `/Organizer.html` if they are not at the root of your application.